# function split() deprecated and explode ....Undefined offset: 1 E_NOTICE Error in file

Tags: php, split, undefined, offset, deprecated

I received this error: `function  split()  deprecated`

```
list ($kk, $vv) = split( '  ', $buf, 2);
```

When I replaced it  with `explode` or `preg_split`  I  got this  error  `Undefined offset: 1 E_NOTICE Error in file`

```
list ($kk, $vv) = explode( "  ", $buf, 2);
```

This  is  the  full  code

```
function get_toprotatingbanners()
{
    $s = array ();
    $file = fopen ('inc/adsadmin/toprotatingbanners.php', 'r');
    if ($file)
    {
        while ($buf = fgets ($file, 20000))
        {
            $buf = chop ($buf);
            if (($buf != '<?/*' AND $buf != '*/?>'))
            {
                list ($kk, $vv) = explode(" ", $buf, 2);
                $s[$kk] = $vv;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose ($file);
    return $s;
}
```

Please  help  me.

Comment: please need  you  guys  precious  help

Comment: @alexeevyci  how am i  going to  make  $buff  deffined. if  that  is  the  problem, write  the code  for  me. please

Answer (score 5):

Function split is deprecated "This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0." as you can see on [php.net/manual/en/function.split.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

Undefined offset: 1 is because $buf is undeffined.

Comment: how  can i  make  $buff  deffined. what are  those thing i have to add. please  help  me

Comment: @selemo, to define `$buf` add a statement at the start such as `$buf = "";`. Now it is defined.

Comment: Please be careful when referencing external links. The English version must be used in this area of Stack Overflow. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Warning
This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Alternatives to this function include:

```
preg_split()
explode()
str_split()
```